# ExecuteReader execution timeout expired when looping

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I am sorry before because the title too general. I just wonder how it's happen in this code:

```
foreach (var item in list)
{
     .........
     using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT some_fields FROM tbl WHERE id=@id", new SqlConnection(db.ConnectionString)))
     {
           cmd.Connection.Open();
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", item.id);

           var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
           while (reader.Read())
           {
                //do something
           }
           cmd.Connection.Close();
     }
     .........
}
```

Execution timeout happened on the second loop. First loop was no problem. Is there something wrong in this syntax? Please tell me.

Exception thrown at ExecuteReader():

```
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at HPM_WEB.Areas.InventoryManagementForms.Transaction.OutboundTransaction.InsertOrUpdateDetailOutbound(MOutboundAdviseModel mout, List`1 doutList, SqlConnection connection, SqlTransaction transaction, String message) in F:\MyFolder\..\Transaction.cs:line 444
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, its something wrong in code you didn't share. What's in the loop part? "Do something" might take years.

Comment: hmm, but the exception happen on var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); @Reniuz. Actually it just set up some variable from result query of course.

Comment: Please add exception details. Message, relevant part of stacktrace

Comment: Just one suggesstion- since you are executing this within a loop keep the `cmd.Connection.Open();` and `cmd.Connection.Close();` outside the loop. You don't have to open and close the connection everytime. This will make your execution faster.

Comment: Is it really necessary to query each item seperately from the database? It would be much faster if you query all items in one SQL-statement and then loop through the results. Especially if you have a lot of items in your list.

Comment: How many records query returns? Do it reach loop? How long it takes to execute reader before the exception?

Comment: only 1 row @Reniuz. So far, I set timeout for 3 minutes and it still got the exception on the second loop.

Comment: how long one loop iteration takes?

Answer (score 2):

Try increasing the Connection Timeout

```
// Setting command timeout to 3 Minutes (60*3=180 Seconds)
cmd.CommandTimeout = 60*3;
```

Do this before `ExecuteReader()`

How long it takes for your `cmd.ExecuteReader();` to execute?

Answer (score 0):

in your connectionstring, you may want to get a try by allowing multiple active resultset.

see if this resolve your issue? like:

```
<add name="yourDBConn" connectionString="Data Source=yourInstance;Initial Catalog=yourDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=pwd;Connection Timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Answer (score 0):

A value of 0 indicates no limit (an attempt to execute a command will wait indefinitely).

The default is 30 seconds. if Read requires two network packets, then it has 30 seconds to read both network packets. If you call Read again, it will have another 30 seconds to read any data that it requires.(Here is the problem exist before expiring timeout it is again calling reader )

Solution 1 is increasing the connection timeout or setting the value to Zero. Another Solution  might work  is use `using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();`