# ExecuteReaderAsync timeout when looping

Tags: c#, sql-server

This is a follow up question to this one who got no accepted answer:

[ExecuteReader execution timeout expired when looping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45542648/executereader-execution-timeout-expired-when-looping)

I am making a loop which invoke this method on every call:

```
private async Task<DataTable> Select(SqlCommand command)
{
SqlConnection connection = null;

DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
try
{
    connection = await GetSqlConnection();
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    await OpenConnectionUsingPolly(connection); //for retries


    using (SqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
    {
        dataTable.Load(reader);
    }

    await command.DisposeAsync();
}
catch (Exception excp)
{
    Logging.Error($"Error reading data (select)\n{excp.Message}");
    throw;
}
finally
{
    connection?.Close();    
    connection?.Dispose();
}

return dataTable;
}
```

The first iteration always works but the second one always gets times out on await command.ExecuteReaderAsync().. what could cause it?

Comment: Where does it timeout? What does GetSqlConnection do? And what's OpenConnectionUsingPolly

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a trick question or not, but timeouts can be caused by queries that exceed the timeout limit. For instance, if the timeout is set to 30 seconds and the queries runs for 40 seconds - you get a timeout. Sometimes it happens that the DB you are connecting to is not responding (so eventually the client gets a timeout error).

Comment: The timeout happens in await command.ExecuteReaderAsync()

Comment: It's the same query all the time in the loop so why would it succeed the first time?

Comment: i'm guessing you have non-reentrant code, or perhaps you share same connection. Who knows though, your code is not enough to solve the issue. what happens if you remove the awaits and change everything to sync

Comment: at the end of the method there's a connection close and dispose, so it's not the same connection. I tried changing the await command.ExecuteReaderAsync() to just command.ExecuteReader() but it didn't help

Comment: How are you calling this code, are you `await`ing it? Side note: no need for all that `finally` `Close` `Dispose` business, just put a `using` on `connection`.

Comment: Yes there's await from the top to the bottom

Answer (score 0):

because `command` defautt time out is 30seconds increase the time by using

```
command.CommandTimeout = desiredSeconds; //60000,100000
```

why don't you use ADO.NET `SqlDataAdapter` class it has in build features to fill the `DataTable` or `DataSet`  directly instead of Looping

Small Example of that

```
    await using SqlConnection sqlConnection = new(GetConnectionString());
    await sqlConnection.OpenAsync();
    SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new(sqlQuery, sqlConnection);
    await sqlConnection.CloseAsync();
    DataTable dt = new();
    sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
```

Comment: You don't need to open and close a connection when using a dataadapter

Comment: The query itself is the same, but with different parameters each loop